# Query parameters not taken into account in Restangular

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I am using Restangular on my front-end and I want to query this URL:

```
http://localhost:4000/study?projectId=123456
```

It returns a list of studies associated to a certain project. So I have the following controller code for the moment:

```
MyApp.controller('ProjectDetailCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams, Restangular) {
    // [...]
    var resource = Restangular.all('study');
    console.log($routeParams.projectId); // displays "123456", the current projectId
    resource.getList('study', {projectId: $routeParams.projectId}).then(function(studies){
        // Doing stuff 
    });
});
```

But it does not return the data I want. Indeed, when I look in the Network panel of Firefox, it queries `http://localhost:4000/study`, as if the parameter was not specified...
It seems to be the [same code that the author give on Github](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#lets-code), and every question on the web seems to use the same syntax. Why is my parameter ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter of the `getList` should be your query params. You've already specified the study bit of your url. You had an extra "study".

```
var resource = Restangular.all('study');
resource.getList({ projectId: $routeParams.projectId }).then(function(studies) {
    // do stuff
});
```

Comment: Seriously, I feel ashamed... Works like a charm :)